# How to input parameters without using command-line parameters

Tags: c#, powershell, cmd

I need to launch program **jphide** (https://github.com/h3xx/jphs) many times in the cycle

Example:
jphide  input-jpeg-file  output-jpeg-file  file-to-be-hidden

I tryed to use command line to transmit the parameters to program

```
public static void Hide(string imagePath, string passWord)
    {
        Collection<PSObject> results;

        string fullPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(imagePath);
        string pathToOutFile = ".\\outImages\\" + imagePath;
        pathToOutFile = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(pathToOutFile);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("test.txt", new string[] { passWord });
        string hiddenFile = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(@".\test.txt");
        RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();

        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
        runspace.Open();

        RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);

        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

        //Here's how you add a new script with arguments
        Command myCommand = new Command(@".\script.bat");

        CommandParameter pathParameter = new CommandParameter(fullPath);
        CommandParameter passWordParameter = new CommandParameter(passWord);
        CommandParameter pathToOutputFileParameter = new CommandParameter(pathToOutFile);
        CommandParameter pathToHiddenFileParameter = new CommandParameter(hiddenFile);
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(pathParameter);
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(passWordParameter);
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(pathToOutputFileParameter);
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(pathToHiddenFileParameter);

        pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);

        // Execute PowerShell script
        results = pipeline.Invoke();
    }
```

**script.bat**

```
jphide "%1" "%3" "%4" 
%2 
%2
```

But in doesn't work. This program after executing 
jphide  input-jpeg-file  output-jpeg-file  file-to-be-hidden
ask me Passphrase 2 times

```
C:\Users\Kostyaj\Downloads\JpegTest\JpegTest\JpegTest\bin\Debug>jphide 067.jpg 068.jpg test.txt

Welcome to jphide Rev 0.51  (c) 1998 Allan Latham <alatham@flexsys-group.com>
This program is freeware.
No charge is made for its use.
Use at your own risk. No liability accepted whatever happens.
Contains cryptogaphy which may be subject to local laws.

Passphrase:
Re-enter  :
```

which i need to input manually

How i can write script or change C# code to automate input Passphrase and Re-enter?

**UPD**

This code

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.RedirectStandardInput = true;

var process = Process.Start(info);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("jphide \"" + pathParameter.Name + "\" \""  + pathToOutputFileParameter.Name + 
            "\" \"" + pathToHiddenFileParameter.Name + "\"");
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("echo " + passWord);
```

creates this output in the command line:

```
jphide "C:\Users\Kostyaj\Downloads\JpegTest\JpegTest\JpegTest\bin\Debug\067.jpg" "C:\Users\Kostyaj\Downloads\JpegTest\JpegTest\JpegTest\bin\Debug\outImages\067.jpg" "C:\Users\Kostyaj\Downloads\JpegTest\JpegTest\JpegTest\bin\Debug\test.txt" || echo aaa

Welcome to jphide Rev 0.51  (c) 1998 Allan Latham <alatham@flexsys-group.com>
This program is freeware.
No charge is made for its use.
Use at your own risk. No liability accepted whatever happens.
Contains cryptogaphy which may be subject to local laws.

Passphrase:
Re-enter  :

C:\Users\Kostyaj\Downloads\JpegTest\JpegTest\JpegTest\bin\Debug>echo 1234
1234
```

But the program had been stopped to wait input of PassPhrase. I typed it and the execution went on

I need to input "1234" automatically in the program jphide

Comment: Can't you just try in the passphrase?

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect the standard input you can then write to the standard input to fill in the passphrase, for example:

```
        var info = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
        info.UseShellExecute = false;
        info.RedirectStandardInput = true;

        var process = Process.Start(info);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("echo Hello World");
```